# Frontend query and does not need to log in

Tags: post-meta

I would like to query a post meta called 3-serial on the frontend page. Once queried, start_date and end_date will appear. I do not know where to put the codes too.

Comment: Probably in a template in your theme, so that it generates HTML for the start and end date at the point you want it to appear. Can you explain in more detail though please - which is the frontend page, any post displayed in the front end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please describe your question in detail or add the code that you have wrote, well
I am assuming that you have written the code for querying post meta.
If yes and by reading your question I believe that you just want to run the code only for frontend page.
if yes then you can use `is_front_page()`.

[Check this reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/)